# Automapper 5.1.1 Can't map Complex object, aways invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, automapper, automapper-5

Here's my issue, I'm trying to map both this entities, and I aways get an exception:

**From:**

```
public int IdCorpoGestor { get; private set; }
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Federacao { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DataIniMandato { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DataFimMandato { get; private set; }
    public string Telefone1 { get; private set; }
    public string Telefone2 { get; private set; }
    public int IdConselho { get; private set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdConselho")]
    public Conselho Conselho { get; private set; }
    public int IdTipo { get; private set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdTipo")]
    public Indicador Tipo { get; private set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; private set; }
}
```

**To:**

```
public class CorpoGestorDTO
{
    public int IdCorpoGestor { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Federacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataIniMandato { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFimMandato { get; set; }
    public string Telefone1 { get; set; }
    public string Telefone2 { get; set; }
    public int IdConselho { get; set; }
    public int IdTipo { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CorpoGestor, CorpoGestorDTO>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Tipo, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Tipo.Nome)));
```

Calling Mapper from DataBase result:

```
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CorpoGestor>, List<CorpoGestorDTO>>(result);
```

Exception:

> > Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

**EDIT**

Openned an issue at the GitHub for AutoMapper, you can have more information there: [Automapper 5.1.1 Can't map Complex object, aways invalid #1783](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1783)

Comment: Problem with these properties: Tipo, [ForeignKey("IdTipo")]
    public int IdTipo { get; private set; }, [ForeignKey("IdConselho")]
    public int IdConselho { get; private set; },  public Conselho Conselho { get; private set; }

Comment: I have pointed out the properties, you can look into them and fix

Comment: @viveknuna What should I do? Ignore?

Comment: fix datatype, define if not defined in To Class

Comment: @viveknuna didn't get it! Define what and where?

Comment: The data types for the `Tipo` property are not the same.  If you want to map that property, you'll need to add a map from `Indicador` to `string`.

Comment: What type of property "Indicador.Nome"? Does it string? I can suggest to check your configuration by using Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); Usually it shows most of the problems

Comment: Can you post exception details?

Comment: do you ever use the reverse mapping anywhere? can you show us the exception details?

Comment: Everything need is posted at the edit that I comment at the end of the question

Comment: _"The exception is very generic"_ well it's not what generic, as you posted on github you are missing mappings for Conselho -> ConselhoResponse

Comment: @IoanaStoian Look the gist configuration file, It is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<CorpoGestor, CorpoGestorDTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Indicador, string>().ConvertUsing(x=> x.Nome);
}
```

You need to convert one data type to another.  To do that, the second line is added to your mapping configuration.

Also, you should only call this *once*.  Doing it multiple times will overwrite previous configurations.

Comment: @Fals is using  .ForMember(x => x.Tipo, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Tipo.Nome)), so problem not in this field.

Comment: @Amy Does't Work! Same problem persisting, even with this modification!

Comment: Doesn't work doesn't tell us anything useful.  We need more information than that.

Comment: @Amy see the Edit, I provided full information on GitHub, and a Gist

Comment: @Amy just edit the answer saying that You should only call Mapper.Initialize once, that was my problem, I was overwriting my previous config with an invalid one

Comment: Ahh, that would do it.